# Simultaneous function with three variables using subsititution method

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Use any substitution method and solve the following equations:
$$2x+5y+7z=86$$
$$3x+y+5z=60$$
$$x+4y+3z=54 $$
I used $x+4y+3z=54$ to make $x$ the subject $x=54-4y-3z$.

Comment: Replace x in the first 2 equations with (54 - 4y - 3z). That gives you 2 equations with the variables y and z. Use the substitution method again on these 2 equations to solve for either y or z.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x+5y+7z=86\\$$
$$3x+y+5z=60\\$$
$$x+4y+3z=54$$
$\\$
$$x=\frac{86-5y-7z}{2}\\$$
$$3(86-5y-7z)+2(y+5z)=2\times 60\\$$
$$86-5y-7z+2(4y+3z)=2\times54$$
$\\$
$$x=\frac{86-5y-7z}{2}\\$$
$$13y+11z=138\\$$
$$3y-z=22\\$$
$\\$
$$x=\frac{86-5y-7z}{2}\\$$
$$y=\frac{138-11z}{13}\\$$
$$3(138-11z)-13z=13\times22\\$$
$\\$
$$x=\frac{290}{23}\\$$
$$y=\frac{190}{23}\\$$
$$z=\frac{64}{23}$$

Comment: I prefer OP's first step, $x=54−4y−3z.$ You have a clever shortcut, performing the substitution _and_ multiplying all terms by a constant to clear the denominator in one step; efficient, but possibly difficult to follow if one is still learning the fundamentals of substitution.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But in the other hand, the OP must struggle to understand the solution.